# How to make a string a HTML ref?

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, awk, sed

I do have following line

1234, alex, san ramón, ca, usa

I want first column "1234" to be a html href.

Expected output

```
<a href="url">1234</a>,alex, san ramón, ca, usa
```

Comment: Have you tried concatenation, string formatting... anything, really?

Comment: I tried Sed/Awk but Not able store string in variable and then append at end.

Comment: show the code and output

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning it's better to post your script so that people can point out and correct your mistakes.

Here is a solution with awk

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{print "<a href=\"url\">"$1"</a>"$2,$3,$4}'
```

fields can be accessed by $1,$2, etc.  Field separator and output field separator set to comma

Answer (score 0):

Using formating and spliting:

```
def link (url, strtitle):
    strtitle = strtitle.split(",")
    title = strtitle[0].strip()
    rest = ",".join(strtitle[1:]).strip()
    return '<a href="%s">%s</a>,%s' % (url, title, rest)
```

You weren't exactly clear on what you want. Awk in Python, Python in shell, awk in shell, awk in Python. Only Python, only awk...

If you want people to answer you, you have to be more explicit.

If you want to get result of this from a shell, save my code with the execution line on top, give it execution permission,  and add:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    sys.stdout.write(link(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

in the code (before you save it. :D    ).
Then from a shell:

```
$ echo $('./as_you_saved_me <url> "1234, alex, san ramón, ca, usa"')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#[^,]*#<a href="url">&</a>#'
```

with a bit of security if number is not present

```
sed 's#^\([0-9]\{1,\}\),#<a href="url">\1</a>,#'
```